# SUM with IF or ALLEXCEPT

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table:
[image: Sample Table]

I want to calculate the following loyalty rate: how many customers that purchased at least one item in 2017 have made a new purchase in 2018?

I tried to create a new column, a new measure…but with no results.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a calculated column with the following formula:

```
Returning customer = IF(Table1[2018]>0 && Table1[2017]>0;1;0)
```

This will return 1 if it is a returning customer and 0 if not a returning customer.

Comment: Hello @Christoffer, is the condition enough?  I must be sure that a specific customer ID has made at least one purchase in 2107 and at least one in 2018, not only in 2018

Comment: Sorry, changed the formula with another condition.